# How do I make the "tree" command slower?

Tags: bash, shell

It started out as "how do I impress my friends when they look at my screen" and now I'm actually very intrigued by this question:

*Is there a way to make the `tree` command in Ubuntu "slower"?*

I don't mean maxing out CPU usage and then having it execute slower, I mean is there a way to set a limit on lines being written to the terminal per millisecond? So that instead of `tree` printing everything at once, it prints one line every (for example) 100 milliseconds.

I haven't found anything related to that searching the web.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the output of `tree` line by line and sleep a bit after outputting each:

```
tree | while read -r line ; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
    sleep 0.1
done
```